# blender + unity rig animation at which level?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

hi i am a beginner in unity and blender both.

here is my question

i created 1 player character with rig and make 1 animation of moving hand like punching in boxing game.
now if i put another character, on whom my player is going to punch, required animation to show the reaction of punch or it will be done by unity it self?

and if this is right (i have to create the animation for reaction), so is that in all the game like vice city player moving and fell down on floor etc. etc...?

Comment: Unity will not automagically create a response animation. Unless you set up a ragdoll system perhaps, but even that does not happen automatically and will require some scripting. Other than that, your question is rather unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is: "*Will Unity make animations for you by itself?*" then the answer is **no**. You have to create your own animations using either Unity's built-in tools or 3D modeling software.

On the other hand if your question is: "*Will Unity automatically trigger animations depending on circumstances?*" then the answer is yes and no. **Yes**, you can make an [animation tree](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Animator.html) which reads your script's variables and changes the animation accordingly. **No**, since you have to make the scripts and the animator.